# Session Values Fails to Load on Request but Loads on Next Request

Tags: node.js, session, redis, handlebars.js

As a newbie to node, I am getting more confused for several days now, and I think I can't withstand the stress anymore. So I think my only way out is to post my challenge here after goggling and attempting any means I can without any positive result.
I am using express with node, together with the express-session and redis to build my app. Meanwhile, I am using Mysql database to store my data, and redis to store sessions. Everything seem to be working normal, but the issue has got to do with my session variables. When I store a value in session, and try's to retrieve it, it won't load, meanwhile, the value is output perfectly in the console. However, when I try to request something else, then the previous session value is displayed. So is like previous sessions gets loaded on current request. I am using handlebars as my template. I just don't know what I am doing wrong, but all the same, this is strange. As I pointed out, previous session value loads on next request or say current request loads previous session values. Any suggestions please?

Comment: can you share a part of your code where you are facing the issue

Comment: @marvel308 Thanks for the concern. Unfortunately, if necessary then I have to post the whole app here, which might not be appropraite. But I think if I scale the issue down better, it will give you a better idea of what I am facing. The problem now is, the session is set alright, but first, I don't see it under chrome sessions under applications, meanwhile, a cookie is seen there. Secondly, the session is rendered in the view only when I make a second post request. Infact, at some point it will be rendered, and at some point too it will not render at all.

Comment: Well! Thanks to all those who were concerned about my challenge....I am so greatful, esp. @marvel308. I have manage to solve the problem. It was an issue with the way I was posting to the server. I was posting the request through ajax, and was trying to either redirect or render the view, and that was what was causing that problem. So finally, I used the success method of the ajax to redirect, whiles I used res.send to output the expected feedback. Thanks once again!